# Python popen doesn't capture stderror

Tags: python-2.7, popen

I need to be able read stdout and stderr as it occurs from a process that I spawn in Python, I am currently using:

```
task = Popen('sh job.sh', stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
with task.stdout:
    for line in iter(task.stdout.readline, b''):
        stream.append(line)
        fileHandle.write(line)
```

This is getting the stdout, but stderr is getting sent to the console:

```
./tmp_2edd9d49-4108-43e8-a09f-30f34488c531: line 1: @echo: command not found
```

I tried adding stderr=PIPE, but that made the errors vanish.  Is there a way of doing this so I can read both (I really would like the error to occur at right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't omit the stderr argument if you want to capture it!

```
import subprocess as shell

raw_cmd = 'sh job.sh'
cmd_list = raw_cmd.split()

task = shell.Popen.(cmd_lst, stdout=shell.PIPE, stderr=shell.PIPE)

with task.stderr as stderr:
    for line in stderr:
        print line

with task.stdout as stdout:
    for line in stdout:
        print line
```

Basically the extern program writes into two files: `stdout` and `stderr`, we plug these "out-files" into our program. The way we are doing that in this example allows only to track the output of either stderr, or stdout in total, so right now there is no correlation.

To track both files simultaneously, you would have to fall back to select, pool, or epoll. Depending on installed libraries and OS.

e.g. on linux:

```
...    
from select import select
...
while 1:
    # `select` blocks until any file is ready !!!
    reads, writes, errors = select([task.stdout, task.stderr], [], [])
    for stdfile in reads:
       if stdfile == task.stdout:
          for line in stdfile: print "stdout:", line
       if stdfile == task.stderr:
          for line in stdfile: print "stdERR:", line

 ...
```

Beware, the code above is untested, but would allow a tighter out/err correleation. This is also not an optimal solution, just a pointer to possible venues.

You let `select` block until any of the specified files/PIPES are ready. Then you check which file is ready (e.g `if stdfile == task.stderr`) you print it and repeat the loop with `select`.

If you don't want this loop to block, you could move them into a separate therad, or make select non-blocking and do multiple polls (see [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)).

Comment: Sorry I was simplifying for question and it was a list.

Comment: Did you also include the `stderr` argument? Btw you don't need the sentinel form of `iter`, if nothing speaks against a line-wise capture with a simple `for`-loop.

Comment: I tried this with   task = Popen(callArg, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1)
  with task.stderr:
   for line in task.stderr:

Comment: It does, just add another `with/for` block. Btw, you can omit the bufsize argument, because bufsize=1 means line oriented, which is done implicitly by using `for line in <file-object>:` !

Comment: added 2nd with task.stderr:
   for line in iter(task.stderr.readline, b''): but that puts the error after the stdout, how do I get them in the right order please?

Comment: That's a problematic one. I assume you know already, what i'm going to say, but just to be clear i will do it nevertheless. See updated answer...